# Is a good practice to keep Retrofit instances in memory?

Tags: android, performance, caching, retrofit, retrofit2

Should I cache objects generated by Retrofit or is it recommended to create on the fly?

I am starting a gradual migration from an old networking framework to Retrofit which started with a very basic logic to cache Retrofit created instances. This is due to our architecture which will use different endpoints in different Activities/Fragments, this method will be called as the user visit different parts of the app:

```
static public <T> T getApi(Class<T> apiInterface) {
  validateInitialization("getApi()");

  if (!mApis.containsKey(apiInterface.getSimpleName())) {
    mApis.put(apiInterface.getSimpleName(), retrofit().create(apiInterface));
  }

  return (T) mApis.get(apiInterface.getSimpleName());
}
```

However as we continue migrating our schemas to use Retrofit, this map is increasing in size (currently around 20 different interfaces/apis can be created) and sometimes contains instances that are no longer used.

Comment: singleton with dagger2 and inject where required. Does https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/di/AppModule.java help?

Answer (score 6):

I would say that the answer is "it depends".

There is no downside (that I am aware of) to caching these objects that is inherent to Retrofit; it's not like these service objects are massive drains on the device's battery life or something wacky like that.

Instead, it comes down to which downside you would prefer to avoid: the potential consumption of "extra" memory by service objects that won't be used again but can't be garbage collected, or the potential "slowness" incurred by creating a new service object for every call. The only way to choose is to analyze your app and your users' behaviors/preferences, and decide which way you'd rather go.

In my personal experience, I have not worried about the performance cost of creating a new service object on the fly. I have never noticed any perceivable difference in my apps' speed as a result of doing this.

In general, I would advice against optimizing *before* you have proof of a problem. I have no proof that `Retrofit.create()` is too slow for my use cases, so I call it on the fly every time.

Comment: This is the real deal " I would advice against optimizing before you have proof of a problem. " and it's valid for all software development.